# Enabling/disabling submit button based on user credentials in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a web application which includes JSP and servlets.  I want to enable certain submit buttons within forms only to a person with username called "admin" and password "admin". I am getting the user credentials from the login.jsp page and passing them to a servlet and then getting back to displayrecord.jsp where I want test if username="admin" and Password="admin" then enable the edit,delete and upload or else disbale them. But unfortunately this does not work.

Here is the code within JSP page for getting value from the servlet

```
<%
    String uname= (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
    String upass= (String)session.getAttribute("UserPassword");
    %>
```

Here is the code which I tried for testing the condition using JSTL

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="{<%=uname%> == 'admin'}&& {<%=upass%> == 'admin'}">
            <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
            </form>
            <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
            </form>
            </c:when>
            </c:choose>
            <c:otherwise>
            <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
            </form>
            <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
            <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
            <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
            </form>
            </c:otherwise>
```

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong or any better way to test the condition for enabling or disabling buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scriplet code will be insertedd into page directly where as jstl variables are scope based. So add username and password into pagecontext and access them using jstl.

```
    <%
     String uname= (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
     String upass= (String)session.getAttribute("UserPassword");
     pageContext.setAttribute("uname",uname);
     pageContext.setAttribute("upass",upass);
    %>
```

and change jstl code as:

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="{uname == 'admin' && upass == 'admin'}">
            <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
            </form>
            <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
            </form>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <form id="edit" action="EditRecord" method="post" >
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_edit" id="edit_id" value="<%=s %>"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"> </td>
            </form>
            <form id="delete" action="DeleteRecord" method="post" >
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden_delete" id="delete_id" value="<%=s %>"/>
                <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="delete" name="delete"> </td>
            </form>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

You closed c:choose right after c:when. You need to close after c:otherwise. That way it ensures to display otherwise content when condition fails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code in JSP page but the page.addAttribute thorws an error as the  pageContext does not has function called addAttribute. Are you sure it is pageContext.addAttribute..

Comment: Also I obtained the username and password in ${UserName} and ${UserPassword} using EL. How can I use EL to check condition and disable the submit button..Kindly guide me

Comment: It should be set Attribute. Updated my answer try and check now.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work..the buttons were disabled for both "admin" user credentials as well as other credentials...Can we try EL for the checking the condition

Comment: I tested this code before posting. Clean up/ remove and try using it from here.

Comment: I did clean the project and copied the entire code what you given..the problem is it not going into when loop, instead it is going into otherwise loop and disabling the button irrespective of user credentials. I also captures the values usin EL (${UserName} and ${UserPassword})..can we try using EL

Comment: Did you specify the uname correctly in page context same as in when condition? Post your code again.

Comment: I need a small guidance. I have table which fetches data from MySQL table. I also have a filter to filter the table records. I want to export the resulting table to excel format or text format..Could you suggest me how can I approach this need...

Comment: Look into apache poi.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the condition to:

```
 <c:when test="{uname == 'admin' && upass == 'admin'}">
```